# Checkbox tag not working properly in Anuglar jS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, checkbox

I'm building a web app which has a form with many different types of questions. Now, I'm suffering with checkbox type of questions.

Here is the view:

```
            <div class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.$submitted && form[field.id].$invalid }" ng-if="field.type === 'checkbox'">
                <label for="{{field.id}}">{{field.title}}</label>
                <br>
                <label ng-repeat="value in field.values"><input type="checkbox" id="{{field.id}}" name="field.id" ng-model="formData[field.id]"> {{value.title}}</label>
                <p class="form-group-note" ng-if="field.info" ng-bind="field.info"></p>

                <div ng-show="form.$submitted" ng-cloack>
                    <span class="help-block" ng-show="form['{{field.id}}'].$error.required" ng-if="field.validations.required">Please enter a value, this field is required</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is a JSON I'm rendering:

```
{
                        "id": "4_6_yes_no_question",
                        "title": "6. Do you qualify for this?",
                        "type": "checkbox",
                        "info": "If yes, check yes",
                        "size": {
                            "width": 100,
                            "height": 1
                        },
                        "validations": {
                            "required": true
                        },
                        "values": [
                            {
                                "id": 0,
                                "title": "Not Selected"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "title": "Yes"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "title": "No"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
```

When my view is shown, it shows 3 checkboxes with different titles(not selected, yes, no). The problem is that when a user selects one of the boxes, it selects all. And the data being saved to localStorage is only true or false. Is it possible to save as the tile I have in JSON?

Comment: They have the same `ng-model`, so when you click one check box, the others will checked too. You need replace `ng-model="value.id"` because you use repeat `value in field.values`. What is your formData? Can you put your code online?

Comment: @DieuNQ FormData is a variable name for localStorage.

Comment: Try this: `ng-model="formData[value.title]"`. Hope this help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, this is a Yes or No question. You cannot select both. So you need to make it Radio button.

Now you can add a `value="{{field.id}}"` to the `input` element so that you get to chose what value is stored in the `ng-model`. And initiate the `ng-model` at the the parent element of that section of your form using `ng-init="formData[field.id]=0"`. It will make `Not selected` option ckecked by default.

**A demo:**

```js
angular.module('theApp', []).controller('theCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.field = {
    "id": "4_6_yes_no_question",
    "title": "6. Do you qualify for this?",
    "type": "radio",
    "info": "If yes, check yes",
    "size": {
      "width": 100,
      "height": 1
    },
    "validations": {
      "required": true
    },
    "values": [{
      "id": 0,
      "title": "Not Selected"
    }, {
      "id": 1,
      "title": "Yes"
    }, {
      "id": 2,
      "title": "No"
    }]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="theApp" ng-controller="theCtrl">
  <div ng-init="formData[field.id]=0" class="form-group" ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.$submitted && form[field.id].$invalid }" ng-if="field.type === 'radio'">
    <label for="{{field.id}}">{{field.title}}</label>
    <br>
    <label ng-repeat="value in field.values">
      <input type="radio" id="{{field.id}}" name="field.id" ng-model="formData[field.id]" value="{{value.id}}">{{value.title}}</label>
    <p class="form-group-note" ng-if="field.info" ng-bind="field.info"></p>

    <div ng-show="form.$submitted" ng-cloack>
      <span class="help-block" ng-show="form['{{field.id}}'].$error.required" ng-if="field.validations.required">Please enter a value, this field is required</span>
    </div>
    
    Selected Value is : {{formData[field.id]}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, I totally missed this part. Yes, checkbox is for boolean not for selecting one out of many. I have further questions. 1. Right now the data is being saved as integer (0,1,2). Is there a way to save the selected data as (not selected, yes, no)?   2. When the form is first opened, the first option is initially selected beacuse of `ng-init="formData[field.id]=0"`. I did get rid of this, but it starts selecting the middle one initially. How do I unselect everything initially?